# PHP - Preg_match shortest matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get "content" from this string:

```
$string = "start start content end";
```

with preg_match like this:

```
preg_match('/start(.*?)end/', $string, $matches);
echo $match[1];
```

but, problem is `$matches[1]` returns `start content` not only `content` because there are two `start` in `$string` (and maybe more)

How to get only `content` part with `preg_match`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a negative lookahead:

```
$string = "start start content end";
preg_match('/start\h*((?:(?!start).)*)end/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
// content
```

`(?:(?!start).)` will match any character if that is not followed by `start`.

Comment: `(?:(?!start).)*` is a so-called [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

Comment: your answers worked for me. 
Thank you and @arunesh-singh

Comment: What is the use of `\h*`? It looks redundant here.

Comment: Without `\h*` output will be `" content"` instead of `"content"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `+` to eat all `start` and then capture your required string.

```
(?:start\s)+(.+?)end
```

Comment: Interesting, since OP is using a `preg_match`, this approach can be valid, but with a regex like `(?:.*start\s)+(.+?)end`.